# How to combine tidyr::pivot_longer with stringr::separate_rows in one shot

Tags: r, reshape, tidyr, stringr

I'm trying to pivot data from wide to long format according to column names, which I can easily accomplish with `tidyr::pivot_longer()`. However, I also need to deconstruct the contents of a specific cell in the wide format – i.e., parsing the string inside of it – and separate the parsed components along the pivoted (longer) rows. While the parsing & separating task is easily done with `stringr::separate_rows`, I don't know how to combine both pivoting and separating procedures in the same shot.

### Data

```r
df <- data.frame(
  id = 1:3,
  blue_type1 = 110:112,
  purple_type5 = 5:7,
  black_type1 = 28:30,
  batch_number = c("bgd | ddg | qwe",
                   "afp | qqw | edt",
                   "pqr | khp | rty")
  )

df

##   id blue_type1 purple_type5 black_type1    batch_number
## 1  1        110            5          28 bgd | ddg | qwe
## 2  2        111            6          29 afp | qqw | edt
## 3  3        112            7          30 pqr | khp | rty
```

### What I want

Convert to long format and unpack `batch_number` such that the first substring will be assigned to the first row in long format, the second substring to the second row, and the 3rd substring to the 3rd row.

#### Desired output

```r
## # A tibble: 9 x 5
##      id batch_number color   type  vals
##   <dbl> <chr>        <chr>  <dbl> <dbl>
## 1     1 bgd          blue       1   110
## 2     1 ddg          purple     5     5
## 3     1 qwe          black      1    28
## 4     2 afp          blue       1   111
## 5     2 qqw          purple     5     6
## 6     2 edt          black      1    29
## 7     3 pqr          blue       1   112
## 8     3 khp          purple     5     7
## 9     3 rty          black      1    30
```

### My attempt

If I just `tidyr::pivot_longer`, I get half way there:

```r
df %>% 
  pivot_longer(., 
               -c(id, batch_number), 
               names_to = c("color", "type"), 
               names_pattern = "(.*)_type(.)", 
               values_to = "vals")

## # A tibble: 9 x 5
##      id batch_number    color  type   vals
##   <int> <chr>           <chr>  <chr> <int>
## 1     1 bgd | ddg | qwe blue   1       110
## 2     1 bgd | ddg | qwe purple 5         5
## 3     1 bgd | ddg | qwe black  1        28
## 4     2 afp | qqw | edt blue   1       111
## 5     2 afp | qqw | edt purple 5         6
## 6     2 afp | qqw | edt black  1        29
## 7     3 pqr | khp | rty blue   1       112
## 8     3 pqr | khp | rty purple 5         7
## 9     3 pqr | khp | rty black  1        30
```

If I try to `stringr::separate_rows` on top of that I get the undesired output:

```r
## # A tibble: 27 x 5
## # Groups:   id [3]
##       id batch_number color  type   vals
##    <int> <chr>        <chr>  <chr> <int>
##  1     1 bgd          blue   1       110
##  2     1 ddg          blue   1       110
##  3     1 qwe          blue   1       110
##  4     1 bgd          purple 5         5
##  5     1 ddg          purple 5         5
##  6     1 qwe          purple 5         5
##  7     1 bgd          black  1        28
##  8     1 ddg          black  1        28
##  9     1 qwe          black  1        28
## 10     2 afp          blue   1       111
## 11     2 qqw          blue   1       111
## 12     2 edt          blue   1       111
## 13     2 afp          purple 5         6
## 14     2 qqw          purple 5         6
## 15     2 edt          purple 5         6
## 16     2 afp          black  1        29
## 17     2 qqw          black  1        29
## 18     2 edt          black  1        29
## 19     3 pqr          blue   1       112
## 20     3 khp          blue   1       112
## 21     3 rty          blue   1       112
## 22     3 pqr          purple 5         7
## 23     3 khp          purple 5         7
## 24     3 rty          purple 5         7
## 25     3 pqr          black  1        30
## 26     3 khp          black  1        30
## 27     3 rty          black  1        30
```

How could I incorporate the operation of `separate_rows` while running `pivot_longer`? Is there an elegant way for such a task? Basically I'm looking for a `tidyverse` solution but will be happy with other approaches too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps there is a shorter and more elegant solution but in the meanwhile you can try this. Basic idea is to

1. Add a batch identifier (`batch`) (by `id`) before calling `tidyr::separate_rows`
2. Filter after `tidyr::separate_rows` for the obs where the `batch_number` and the `batch` identifier are equal. For this last step I first convert the `batch_number` to a factor using `forcats::fct_inorder` and then to a numeric which gives me the position of `batch_number` which can then be matched with `batch` identifier

```r
set.seed(42)

df <- data.frame(
  id = 1:3,
  blue_type1 = 110:112,
  purple_type5 = 5:7,
  black_type1 = 28:30,
  batch_number = c("bgd | ddg | qwe",
                   "afp | qqw | edt",
                   "pqr | khp | rty")
)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(forcats)

df %>% 
  pivot_longer(-c(id, batch_number)) %>% 
  group_by(id) %>% 
  mutate(batch = row_number()) %>% 
  separate_rows(batch_number) %>% 
  filter(batch == as.numeric(forcats::fct_inorder(batch_number)))
#> # A tibble: 9 x 5
#> # Groups:   id [3]
#>      id batch_number name         value batch
#>   <int> <chr>        <chr>        <int> <int>
#> 1     1 bgd          blue_type1     110     1
#> 2     1 ddg          purple_type5     5     2
#> 3     1 qwe          black_type1     28     3
#> 4     2 afp          blue_type1     111     1
#> 5     2 qqw          purple_type5     6     2
#> 6     2 edt          black_type1     29     3
#> 7     3 pqr          blue_type1     112     1
#> 8     3 khp          purple_type5     7     2
#> 9     3 rty          black_type1     30     3
```

Answer (score 2):

You can subset the strings in batch_number after you pivot.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(stringr)

df %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  mutate(batch_index = seq.int(1, n()*6, 6)) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  mutate(batch_number = str_sub(batch_number, batch_index, batch_index+2)) %>%
  select(-batch_index)

#      id batch_number color  type   vals
#   <int> <chr>        <chr>  <chr> <int>
# 1     1 bgd          blue   1       110
# 2     1 ddg          purple 5         5
# 3     1 qwe          black  1        28
# 4     2 afp          blue   1       111
# 5     2 qqw          purple 5         6
# 6     2 edt          black  1        29
# 7     3 pqr          blue   1       112
# 8     3 khp          purple 5         7
# 9     3 rty          black  1        30
```

Please note that `mutate(batch_index = seq.int(1, n()*6, 6))` adds a column named batch_index to the data frame (grouped by id). Within each row, batch_index is used to subset the string in batch_number. batch_index is produced by `seq.int(1, n()*6, 6)` and consists of integers from 1 to `n()*6` (i.e. the number of rows in the current group multiplied by six - note that the end value does not have to be this high). The numbers in the sequence are six apart: 1 , 7, 13 ...

`mutate(batch_number = str_sub(batch_number, batch_index, batch_index+2)` uses batch_index to subset the string in batch_number in each row. The first row in a group requires the first substring from batch_number - the function thus subsets batch_number from batch_index (i.e. 1) to batch_index+2 (i.e. 3). The second row in a group needs the second substring from batch_number - the function thus subsets batch_number from batch_index (i.e. 7) to batch_index+2 (i.e. 9) etc.

This works provided that all the substrings in batch_number consist of three letters.

Comment: Thanks @rjen. Although this solution gets the work done given the data provided in the question, it's not scalable to larger datasets, where `batch_number` might include many components to be substringed. Indeed, the data I included in the question is just toy data for demonstrating the problem using a short and simple dataset. In reality, my problem pertains to a much larger dataset.

Comment: You're welcome @Emman. I've generalized the solution to accommodate the info from your comment.

Comment: Thanks again, @rjen. May I ask two more things about this solution? (1) In my real data, the substrings in `batch_number` are longer than 3 characters. Applying your solution on my data trims those substrings to 3 character long, which is not as intended. Can this be adjusted? (2) Would you mind explaining the solution? For example, `mutate(batch_index = seq.int(1, n()*6, 6))`. What's going on inside this line?

Comment: My pleasure, @Emman. I have added some explanation to my post. Please let me know what the substrings in batch_number look like in the real data set. Are they all the same length, or do they fall within a range?

Comment: Hi @rjen, thanks! This is outstanding! In my real data, the substrings are of a constant length, just happens to be much longer than `3`.

Comment: @Emman: Great. That should make for a quick adaptation. As you may have noticed, ```seq.int(1, (n()*6)-5, 6)``` is more precise than ```seq.int(1, n()*6, 6)``` as used the solution above. But the precise formulation is more clunky and the practical difference should be negligible.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `separate_rows` and `pull` inside a `mutate`, after `pivot_longer`:

```r
df %>% 
  pivot_longer(-c(id, batch_number), 
               names_to = c("color", "type"), 
               names_pattern = "(.*)_type(.)", 
               values_to = "vals") %>%
  mutate(batch_number = 
           df %>% 
           separate_rows(batch_number, sep = " \\| ") %>% 
           pull(batch_number)
         ) 

# A tibble: 9 x 5
     id batch_number color  type   vals
  <int> <chr>        <chr>  <chr> <int>
1     1 bgd          blue   1       110
2     1 ddg          purple 5         5
3     1 qwe          black  1        28
4     2 afp          blue   1       111
5     2 qqw          purple 5         6
6     2 edt          black  1        29
7     3 pqr          blue   1       112
8     3 khp          purple 5         7
9     3 rty          black  1        30
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this option using `separate_rows()` from `tidyr` and the use of a sequential id:

```
library(tidyverse)
#Code
df <- df %>% separate_rows(batch_number,sep='\\|') %>%
  mutate(batch_number=trimws(batch_number)) %>%
  group_by(id) %>% mutate(Val=1:n()) %>%
  pivot_longer(-c(id,batch_number,Val)) %>%
  separate(name,c('color','type'),sep='_') %>%
  mutate(type=gsub('type','',type),Flag=ifelse(id==Val,1,0)) %>%
  filter(Flag==1) %>% select(-c(Flag,Val))
```

Output:

```
# A tibble: 9 x 5
# Groups:   id [3]
     id batch_number color  type  value
  <int> <chr>        <chr>  <chr> <int>
1     1 bgd          blue   1       110
2     1 bgd          purple 5         5
3     1 bgd          black  1        28
4     2 qqw          blue   1       111
5     2 qqw          purple 5         6
6     2 qqw          black  1        29
7     3 rty          blue   1       112
8     3 rty          purple 5         7
9     3 rty          black  1        30
```

Comment: Unfortunately this solution is only half of what I'm trying to accomplish. See the desired output I included in the question above. First and foremost I need to pivot longer by column names, _and at the same time_ to `separate_rows`.

Comment: @Emman Sorry, I haven't noticed that detail. I have updated the solution. I hope that can help you!

Comment: Thanks @Duck! But the current output is still not as intended. Compare the `batch_number` column in this solution's output with the `batch_number` column in the desired output and see the difference.